# Failed to read and write xml file with TwinCAT

Tags: xml, twincat

I have a custom function block which can read or write xml files. It can also create a new file, if one with the current name already exists. It does that by appending a number to the filename.

The first xml file is created without a problem (e.g. `1_Filename.xml`). However, if i run the code a second time when it should create `2_Filename.xml`, it gives me [error 1828](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/TcDiagnostics/HTML/TcDiagnostics_ErrorOverview.htm&id=): *Incompatible version of the serializing package*.

Also when I try to load `1_Filename.xml`, it gives me error code 1828.

Finally if I change the "base" filename from `Filename` to `AnotherFilename`, it creates `1_AnotherFilename` without a problem, but fails when trying to create `2_Filename`. Again with the same error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was looking at the wrong error codes. It was not a Win32 error code, but an ADS return code. For some strange reason these two error codes have overlapping numbers!

ADS error [code 1828](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6250_tc3_modbus_tcp/99079192176427915.html&id=) means *Missing license*. Turns out the Tc3 XML-Server license did not get added automatically to my project. I had to manually add and create a trail license for it. Afterwards everything worked.

Comment: Thanks past Roald! Just had this issue again.